# How can I divide table data into multiple tables and keep the relations?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have four tables: *(three o them are empty)*

```
-- all_locations
+----+----------------+---------------+-----------+
| id |      name      | location_type | parent_id |
+----+----------------+---------------+-----------+
| 1  | Aruba          | 0             | 0         |
| 2  | Afghanistan    | 0             | 0         |
| 3  | â€“            | 1             | 1         |
| 4  | Balkh          | 1             | 2         |
| 5  | Herat          | 1             | 2         |
| 6  | Kabol          | 1             | 2         |
| 7  | South Hill     | 2             | 3         |
| 8  | The Valley     | 2             | 3         |
| 9  | Mazar-e-Sharif | 2             | 4         |
| 10 | Herat          | 2             | 5         | 
+----+----------------+---------------+-----------+

-- country
+----+---------+
| id |   name  |
+----+---------+

-- province
+----+---------+-------------+
| id |   name  | country_id  |
+----+---------+-------------+

-- city
+----+---------+-------------+
| id |   name  | province_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

Now I want to divide data of the first table between other tables *(based on the `location_type` valye: `0` means country, `1` means province, `2` means city)* 
 and then drop the first table.

So this is the expected result:

```
-- country
+----+-------------+
| id |     name    |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Aruba       |
| 2  | Afghanistan |
+----+-------------+

-- province
+----+---------+------------+
| id |  name   | country_id |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | â€“     | 1          |
| 2  | Balkh   | 2          |
| 3  | Herat   | 2          |
| 6  | Kabol   | 2          |
+----+---------+------------+

-- city
+----+----------------+-------------+
| id |      name      | province_id |
+----+----------------+-------------+
| 1  | South Hill     | 1           |
| 2  | The Valley     | 1           |
| 3  | Mazar-e-Sharif | 2           |
| 4  | Herat          | 3           | 
+----+----------------+-------------+
```

I can do that by a loop in PHP. Something like this:

```
foreach( $fetched_rows_from_all_locations as $location ){
    switch( $location['location_type'] ){
        case '0':
          -- INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ($location['name'])
          break;

        case '1':
          -- INSERT INTO province(name) VALUES ($location['name'])
          break;

        case '2':
          -- INSERT INTO city(name) VALUES ($location['name'])
          break;
    }
}
```

But my code doesn't handle the relations. As you know, the values into `parent_id` column aren't valid anymore. So I have to make the new ids. How can I do that?

Comment: where is Kabol in the result? and why should the id in the new city table not start with id 1 again?

Comment: are the id columns in the new tables auto increment?

Comment: @EstebanP. My question edited. And yes, `id` column is PK in all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be:

Inserting the countries to the new table - which is the easiest task.

Then inserting the province. Now we have to grab the new IDs of the countries (as the ID column is auto-increment).
First we do a self-JOIN on all_location, to get the parents name.
Then we do a join to the previous new filled table countries on the column name, grab the ID and finally insert the values to the new province table.

Same procedure like above again for the city table.

```
INSERT INTO country (name)
SELECT name
  FROM all_locations
 WHERE location_type = 0

INSERT INTO province(name, country_id)   
SELECT child.name
      ,country.id
  FROM all_locations child
 INNER JOIN all_locations parent
    ON child.parent_id = parent.id
 INNER JOIN country
    ON country.name = parent.name
 WHERE child.location_type = 1  

INSERT INTO city(name, province_id)   
SELECT child.name
      ,province.id
  FROM all_locations child
 INNER JOIN all_locations parent
    ON child.parent_id = parent.id
 INNER JOIN province
    ON province.name = parent.name
 WHERE child.location_type = 2 

DROP TABLE all_locations
```

If you want to reproduce my solution, you can use this link:
http://rextester.com/XQOZ12449